# Service workers - simplest implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I'd like to implement service workers instant load for my website with the simplest implementation possible.

My idea is this - user opens webpage, gets cached version (app shell) and after the server return original content, it will be rerendered. Is that even possible? I couldn't find any example of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the fetch event is called for the request then respond with the app-shell from the cache. and then **wait Untill** your server respond with the result then use **postMessage** to send the data to the browser. In your website's javascript add a **message event listener** and fills the data you receive, in the app-shell using javascript html. your app-shell must have some empty component that can be filled later.

For code reference refer to this link.
https://serviceworke.rs/strategy-cache-update-and-refresh.html